# SSH Login, but the IP not listed in interfaces after login

Tags: networking, ssh

This baffles me a bit. I was able to login to a computer. But after I login, I see that the ip is not listed anywhere in the network interfaces. What could really be happening?

Note: The ssh ip I used is 192.168.86.44 and I logged into computer with the ip address 192.168.86.33

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@192.168.86.44
Welcome to Ubuntu 19.10 (GNU/Linux 5.3.0-1030-raspi2 armv7l)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Tue Jun 15 14:26:41 UTC 2021

  System load:                 0.8
  Usage of /:                  23.5% of 58.42GB
  Memory usage:                21%
  Swap usage:                  0%
  Processes:                   164
  Users logged in:             1
  IP address for eth0:         192.168.86.33
  IP address for docker0:      172.17.0.1
  IP address for cni0:         10.42.0.1
  IP address for veth3116dc16: 169.254.133.97
  IP address for veth6c9cc3a4: 169.254.48.7
  IP address for vethf4a2e522: 169.254.3.237
  IP address for vethb9f00116: 169.254.84.229
  IP address for veth14175803: 169.254.244.162
```

Comment: Could you post the output when connecting while passing the `-v` flag to the command?

Comment: Even in alocal network this depends on your routing. If you use e.g. port forwarding or anything into this direction the IP addresses you would see on the server are not the ones you see on the host.